# How can I remove R in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: r

I do

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
```

and

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base
sudo apt-get remove autoremove
```

but  steel driving R in Ubuntu........

Comment: actually is `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually have R installed? If so, test where the binary is. On a terminal:

```
which R
```

That will give you the path to the binary. No matches? There is no R installed.

Some matches? Maybe you installed R also on your home or compiled it and installed it manually? If there are matches on `/usr/local`, `/opt` or on your home directory, this is probably the case. If so, follow the uninstall instructions included with the files you've installed manually.

Also, maybe there's still some packages laying around. This command will tell you all the installed packages starting with `r-`, which is a good starting point.

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -E "\Wr-"
```